# Windows 10 failed to boot

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I tried to install Windows 10 Pro on a x64 pc.

First attemps always failed after first reboot, with the exception code : `Kmode exception not handled`. Neither Microsoft site nor Google offers help.

I think it's due to hardware conflict, so I unplugged all unnecessary hardware (second hdd, network, audio out jack ...). I left only acdc, dvi and usb for keyboard and mouse.

I was finally able to reach desktop (3 BSoD occured during process). Eventually, BSoD still occurs, with same exception.

I somehow managed to install available updates, and turn off computer.

Next reboot, pc was unable to reach desktop, saying it encounters an exception and asking for reboot. If I wait longer, BSoD with former exception shows up.

I switched ram, changed graphic card, plugged / unplugged second HDD for no success.

Does someone had an idea ?

For what it worth, this is a self mounted pc, and data are backed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible actions in order of severity:

1. Disable Fast Startup
2. Run [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) overnight and check its log
3. Run [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html), and repeat after running the DISM command at the end of this article
4. Check for a BIOS update (only from the manufacturer's website)
5. [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html)
6. Do a clean install of Windows
7. If nothing helps, there is perhaps a hardware error that might need
   professional help.

Comment: It was an outdated BIOS. Upgrade required to reinstall Windows7. Thanks for your help.